# How does one end a sentence correctly when using a quote excerpt?

Tags: quotations, periods

Apologies if this has already been answered, I have searched but couldn't find anything. Also I'm not using American English, so periods are outside of the quotations by default.

What's the correct way to include an excerpt from a quote at the end of a sentence?

> He described it as "...terrible, an absolute disgrace...". Other locals agree with him.
>
> He described it as "...terrible, an absolute disgrace..." Other locals agree with him.
>
> He described it as "...terrible, an absolute disgrace". Other locals agree with him.

I would have guessed the third answer is correct, however not including the "..." seems wrong, as it implies that the quote actually ends, but I may be wrong.

Comment: If the quote did NOT end, I would go with #1. If it DID end, #3

Comment: All of these are correct. And all of these are terrible, an absolute disgrace. Do not use any of them, correct as they might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to include the ellipsis on **either** side of the quoted text—because the quote does not begin with a capital letter, it is implied that it is not the start of a sentence. Additionally, there is no reason to make clear that the sentence does not end with the quoted material you've provided.

Both are unnecessary.

In fact, most *good* writers avoid quoting complete sentences because in most situations, the significance that you, the author, are highlighting is found in only a handful of words.

Comment: The bit about periods is wrong. Seeing how it's also off-topic, I took the liberty of removing it altogether. We have a dedicated question for that.